# How to avoid system databases using SMO object in powershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, backup

How I can avoid System databases while taking backups using SMO object in Powershell

I am trying to take the all available databases excluding system databases.

```
param(
$serverName,
$backupDirectory,
$daysToStoreBackups
)

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum") | Out-Null

$server = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $serverName
$dbs = $server.Databases
foreach ($database in $dbs)
{
$dbName = $database.Name

$timestamp = Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss
$targetPath = $backupDirectory + "\" + $dbName + "_" + $timestamp + ".bak"

$smoBackup = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Backup")
$smoBackup.Action = "Database"
$smoBackup.BackupSetDescription = "Full Backup of " + $dbName
$smoBackup.BackupSetName = $dbName + " Backup"
$smoBackup.Database = $dbName
$smoBackup.MediaDescription = "Disk"
$smoBackup.Devices.AddDevice($targetPath, "File")
$smoBackup.SqlBackup($server)

"backed up $dbName ($serverName) to $targetPath"
}
```

Reference for the script is [SMO Object Backup Script Link for PS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1862/backup-sql-server-databases-with-a-windows-powershell-script/)

Comment: As a side note, [one should](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-and-restore-of-system-databases-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) back up system databases too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
foreach ($database in $dbs)
```

To

```
foreach ($database in $dbs | where { $_.IsSystemObject -eq $False })
```

This should do the trick.